# Matching Excel inventory sheet with scanned UPCs and then feeding that into frontend of a Web App

Tags: microsoft-excel, ecommerce, postgresql, inventory

I have an interesting use-case and I was wondering if my approach seems viable.  I am in the liquidation business and I purchase merchandise by the truckload from an array of national retailers.  I sell by the pallet, but unfortunately, these truckloads come with one manifest for the whole truck and not for the individual pallets themselves.  The end-game would be to list the pallets on a Shopify store manifested individually, which gives the potential buyer much more information on their flip and it also allows me to charge more based off the total MSRP of the pallet.

**Here is the Inventory Flow from Manifest to Frontend of the Website**

- Enter Manifest into a UPC Database (convert from Excel to Postgres).  This will actually be done through a custom backend solution in the web app via Ruby on Rails
- Inventory the individual pallets, as well as scan all the UPCs on the pallet and put it into our WMS (Warehouse Management System).
- Sync up Inventory from WMS to Shopify API
- Query inventory data from Shopify API (this will include the pallet number and its associated UPCs) and search UPC data for corresponding matches.
- Serve up the merged data via an Endpoint from my RoR application.  This should still maintain the integrity of Shopify being the absolute truth regarding my inventory.  The product data is simply a UI component and has nothing actionable about it.

Did I obfuscate the problem or does this seem like a decent option?  And if it's not, is there a better way to handle this through another piece of software?